# What are the optional objectives in Street Sweep missions for?

Tags: watch-dogs, watch-dogs-bad-blood

When you start a Street Sweep mission, an optional objective, like "don't use weapons", is displayed, but after this point the game never seems to bring it up again. What does completing these objectives do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the map it shows the objective, if you fail the objective it will display that you've failed.

Once you finish the mission, it will tell you whether you completed the optional objective:

- For regular missions it will give you an additional street tag. (One tag for completing the mission, another for the objective)
- For the 4 hour challenge missions it gives you additional 20000 points.

Answer (score -2):

[I found a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=UUssah1FcvfT25Juty3UDsNg&v=2FOB6mxIW9g&feature=player_detailpage#t=231) of someone completing one of these missions and getting the optional objective of not using any weapons.

When the leaderboard shows up, he gets additional points for completing the optional objective. So at least for this specific mission, it's a point bonus.

Comment: [I found another video from the same user](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq3KD53vf3M), which covers the "no killing," "remain undetected," and the "under five minutes" challenges, and it looks like completing the optional objectives doesn't really do anything besides add more difficulty and complexity. The previous video I found with the "no weapons" objective seems to have a score tied to it, but I didn't see anything in this video that implies that there is a score tied to the other objectives. I don't personally have the DLC, so I can't do more research. Sorry about that!